# Matching node id with mysql table id

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have to make function where I can get node id from url (`example: localhost/site/node-1`)and make link to mysql databes row where is `(example: id=1)` and i need to do it dynamically with several nodes.. I try this code:

```
<?php

function module_name_menu() {
  $items['node-%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Row from database',
    'page callback' => 'module_name_node_page_view',
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
  );
  return $items;
}

function module_name_node_page_view(){

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $results=db_query("SELECT * FROM csvupload WHERE id = $id");

        $header = array ( t('First name'), t('Last name'), t('Email'));
        $rows = array();

  foreach($results as $result){
    $rows[] = array(
      $result -> first_name,
      $result -> last_name,
      $result -> email,

      );
  }

  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

}
```

When I go to `localhost/site/node-1` I get Page not found. I need to do it with `node-2, node-3`... Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: **SQL Injection alert**  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: For the Page Not Found problem, check if you have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache and properly set up in your .htaccess file. A side problem is that if `node-1` is part of the URI, it won't be in `$_GET`. You'll need to parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to find out which node id the user requested.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to get current page node id, i.e.:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $nid = arg(1);
}
```

Or

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $nid = $node->nid;
}
```

Then, your format:

localhost/site/node-1

is not drupal's url format, but something custom for you. For that you can first use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

to get your custom path. Then, since  your path contains only one "-" sign you can use php explode() function to split by that sign and find string part right from the minus sign.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Also, using views is "more natural" ("drupalish") way for getting content from database, but if your assignment is specific...you have to do it that way. But if you have to load a node, then why are you selecting "csvupload" table instead? Drupal's database organization is a bit more complex than you expect. Not all fields you add to your content type are part of one table. It's more that every field you add is different table and you'll need a lot of joins to get the content you need. That's why it's better to use views...

Comment: I tried with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but still doesn't work.. Can you be more specific..If you have any suggestions it will be helpfull? @MilanG

Comment: How do you mean "it doesn't help"? Did you write it out? What string it contains?

Comment: I am new in drupal so i am not sure if  I do it right way.. Code is: `$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 explode("-", $uri);  $results=db_query("SELECT * FROM csvupload WHERE id = $uri");` The rest is the same..  Hvala unapred @MilanG

Comment: explode() is returning the results and you are just ignoring it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: After every "suspicious" line print out variables you have to make sure what step fails. Before that db_query() call print out $uri to is if it has right value or not.

Comment: I am quite new in php too so I can't figure it out.. When i type `explode("-", $uri); echo $uri;` or `print_r(explode("-", $uri));` I don't get any error.. I get page not found as always before.. @MilanG

Comment: Check out documentation and especially examples for explode() function. It will return an array and you should store it somewhere and then use part with index 1. Something like: $parts = explode('-',$uri); $nid = $parts[1];